# Menu key doesn't appear for my app on honeycomb?

Tags: android

I've got a project which links to API level 11. When I run this on phones, and hit the menu key, my menu shows up fine. When I run on a device which is running android 3.0.1, the menu key does not appear for the same activity:

Any idea why the menu key wouldn't show for this activity?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(...);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(...);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Shouldn't the menu key be appearing for this activity?

Thanks

----- Update --------------------

After some more searching, found this thread on the same issue:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c4b1b835060bd93f

Hackborn says the menu button will be shown if you *do not* target sdk 11. Which I was doing. So I have a very odd setup now:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="5" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

  <application 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
  </application>
</manifest>
```

and in my project properties, I am linked to sdk 11. The reason I'm linking to sdk 11 is so that I can use the "hardwareAccelerated=true" flag in the manifest as above.

So to summarize, I'm linked to sdk 11 in project settings, but setting targetSdkVersion=10 in the manifest. Is that legit? I thought they would have to match,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's legit in that it will work, it's not legit in terms of Android user experience standards. :)

The reason you don't get a menu button in the system bar when you target API 11 is that we only show it for supporting legacy apps. New apps should use the action bar to present options for your activity. The action bar will be populated by the same mechanisms that populate your options menu on previous versions.

Target API 11 and make sure you're not disabling the title bar in your theme or in your activity and you will get an action bar by default. The menu will appear in the upper right.

Comment: That's the most horrible answer I have ever seen! So you purposely disable it for ALL apps and now you're telling me that if I want to target SDK > 10 I have to loose YEARS of development time to revamp the entire app just because??!!? I hate you Google, you're becoming even more evil than Micro$oft!!

Answer (score 1):

That's legit: it'll build fine, and will work fine as well. I'm not aware of any problems that would ensue: the docs explicitly say you can target a lower version than you are building against.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `android:targetVersion` attribute in manifest file 
and use `android:minSdkVersion="8"`
minsdk version should be lower than your device version